# Incremental SVM With Probability Estimates

Tags: python, svm

Is there any implementation of incremental svm which also has the feature of returning the probability of a given feature vector belonging to the various classes? Preferably usable with python code

I have heard about LaSVM. Does LaSVM has a feature of returning probability estimates? Also does it have features for handling imbalance training datasets?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look in [Scikit Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html), a very flexible and efficient library written in Python

In every model, there are stored the internal calculated values. If clf is your SVM classifier, you can access clf.decision_function to see some explanation of the predictions.

It also provides a good set of tools for preprocessing data among other things you can find interesting.

cheers,

Comment: In scikit-learn, only linear SVMs can be trained incrementally (`SGDClassifier` with its `partial_fit` method). But that only supports probabilities when `loss="log"`, and it that case it trains LR instead of an SVM.

Answer (score 0):

For getting probability estimate you can use scikit-learn library. There are 2 alternatives you can use. One gives probabilities. Here is an example: [How to know what classes are represented in return array from predict_proba in Scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937243/how-to-know-what-classes-are-represented-in-return-array-from-predict-proba-in-s) 
And the other gives signed values for ranking (not probability but generally gives better result): [Scikit-learn predict_proba gives wrong answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017882/scikit-learn-predict-proba-gives-wrong-answers) you should look at the answer.